Git log graph of specific commits
Is there a way to use git log --graph to show only a specific set of commits. I.e. I have the hashes of a few commits and I just want to see the relationship between them, but with all other commits elided.

git log --graph first_commit second_commit third_commit should only give you the specific commits and their ancestors.

Or are you looking for something like git log --ancestry-path --boundary --graph $(git merge-base first second)..first second (requires bash or similar)?

@dan1st AFAIU "their ancestors" is the problem that the OP wants to avoid.

@phd For that situation, I have the second command with the git merge-base

@dan1st It surely looks much closer to what the OP wants.

I know of a hack: a. place tragetted refs on this list of commits: git update-ref refs/dec/xx <commit>,  b. use git log --graph --simplify-by-decoration --decorate-refs=refs/dec  (followed by c. cleanup refs). This should get you the graph, however this would also get rid of all the other decorations (like tags and branches) which I, for one, often expect in a git log --graph output.
